# C++ 2D Array input validation

Tags: c++

A competitors are being scored between 0 to 10 by judges.  I want my program to only accept 0-10 value only for the user input, this is my code here

```cpp
    string name [5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{

    cout << "Enter participant's name: \n";
    cin >> name[i];
    cout<<"Enter scores for " << name[i] <<endl;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    
    {
        cin>>scores[i][j];
        if (scores[i][j] < 0 && scores[i][j] > 10)
            cout << "Invalid number. Try again.";
    }
}


for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        sum += scores[i][j];
    }
    cout<<"Total scores of " << name[i] << " " <<" is "<<sum<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (scores[i][j] < 0 && scores[i][j] > 10)` -- How is this possible to be both less than 0 and greater than 10?

Comment: What Paul said. It's good to include the code, but also show us a sample run of what it's doing, plus want you want it to do. Remember it's harder to read code than it is to write it!

Answer (score 0):

Over here, you actually state that the input should be less than zero and grater than 10 at the same time. Basically the condition never gets satisfied. So change this:

```cpp
 if (scores[i][j] < 0 && scores[i][j] > 10)
```

To this:

```cpp
 if (scores[i][j] < 0 || scores[i][j] > 10)
```

But you still input the data to the array anyway. So lets first input it to a variable and if the condition is satisfied, input it to the array.

```cpp
j = 0;
while (j < 2)
{
    int score = 0;
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Invalid number. Try again.";
        continue;    // This says to skip to the next iteration.
    }

    // If the score is within the boundaries, assign it to the array.
    scores[i][j] = score;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i get that now. But i have a problem in displaying the total scores when there I insert invalid numbers (<0 and >10)

Comment: this is my coding 


    int score = 0;
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Invalid number. Try again." << endl;
        j--;
        continue;    // This says to skip to the next iteration.
    }
}
}
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        sum += score;
    }
    cout<<"Total scores of " << name[i] << " " <<" is "<<sum<<endl;
}

Comment: This is how it came out :Total scores of sub  is 2                    
Total scores of sik  is 2                    
Total scores of jae5  is 2

Comment: @alice Why did you change your old sum calculating logic? It works perfectly. You cant use `score` because its out of the scope. And I updated the code to use a `while` loop as its safer.

Comment: @alice By "old sum calculating logic" what I mean is the logic you used in your question.